# An unexpected ratio of an integer

Tags: mathematics

If $\frac{1}{4}$ of 20 is equal to 6, what is $\frac{1}{3}$ of 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely it must be

> 4

because a fourth of 20 is usually 6 only when we are

> working in base-12

Comment: perfect answer!

Comment: Also if you look it in normal base (base 10), 6=1÷4 of 20+1 and 4=1÷3 of 10+1 but it is tagged mathematics so my thoughts are not suitable for this answer.+1 though.